# What makes this snippet not a strict quine?

Tags: python, quine

Does someone know why this is not a strict quine ?

```
_0='_0=%r;print _0%%_0';print _0%_0
```

Comment: How is "strict quine" defined? I can't find a definition for this term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The print statement appends a newline during execution, so you would need to include a newline in the snippet.

[image]